# How do I normalise this json using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask, how do I normalise this json data set using pandas?

```
{
    "customer_id": "C23", 
    "basket": [{
        "product_id": "P32", 
        "price": 1173
    }, {
        "product_id": "P27", 
        "price": 1943
    }], 
    "date_of_purchase": "2018-12-01 23:34:00"
}
```

I would like the output to be something like this:

```
| customer_id | product_id | price | date_of_purchase |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.io.json.json_normalize` specifying your `meta` and `record_paths` args

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_txt, 'basket', ['customer_id', 'date_of_purchase'])
```

Outputs

```
    price   product_id  customer_id date_of_purchase
0   1173    P32         C23         2018-12-01 23:34:00
1   1943    P27         C23         2018-12-01 23:34:00
```